# Error while using Cfchart

Tags: coldfusion

I am cfchart for creating chart in ColdFusion. I used the following code. I use the value of variable in chartdata I am getting error

> "Invalid token c found on line 204 at column 34" i.e. cfchartdata item="0 - 6 Months" value="#count_06#"

Code:

```
<cfchart   
            format="jpg"  
            xaxistitle="Body Part"  
            yaxistitle="Claims"  
            chartheight="500" 
            chartwidth="1000"  
            showlegend = "yes"
            show3d="yes"
            backgroundcolor="##006600"
            foregroundcolor="FFFFFF"  
        >  
            <cfchartseries     
                type="bar" 
                seriescolor="##006600"
                seriesLabel="Claims Number"
                <cfchartdata item="0 - 6 Months" value="#count_06#"/>  
                <cfchartdata item="6 Months - 1 Year" value="#count_61#"/>  
                <cfchartdata item="Over 10 years" value="#count_10#"/>  
            >  
            </cfchartseries>  

        </cfchart>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you haven't closed the openning cfchartseries tag

So do this

```
seriesLabel="Claims Number">
```

instead of this:-

```
seriesLabel="Claims Number"
```